# how to change value 0 of unchecked checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, view

In my problem when I checked a normal value but when unchecking a value of 0. I want to value it when unchecking it is damaged.

```
{!! Former::hidden('machine.status')
          ->id('machine_status_hidden')
          ->name('machine[status]')
          ->value('damaged')
      !!}
{!! Former::checkbox('machine.status')->name('machine[status]')
          ->id('machine_status')
          ->bind('machine.status')
          ->label(' ')->text('finish?')
          ->value('normal')
          ->check($machine->status)!!}
```

Please tell me where is wrong. Why is the script not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I know where is wrong. 
Former have unchecked value 0 and then make former::hidden not working because checkbox and hidden override